# Agora.io Channel Encryption for flutter not working for cross platform

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I’m trying to use channel encryption when perform video/voice call using Agora Flutter SDK. However, when using the encryption function, the video/voice call will not function for cross platform (eg: android call iOS). But work if android call android, or iOS call iOS. Below is my implementation in flutter (outgoingCall.dart). Thank you.

```
Future<void> initialize() async {
 if (APP_ID.isEmpty) {
 setState(() {
 _infoStrings.add('APP_ID missing, please provide your APP_ID in settings.dart',);
_infoStrings.add('Agora Engine is not starting');
  });
 return;
 }

 await _initAgoraRtcEngine();
 _addAgoraEventHandlers();
 AgoraRtcEngine.setAudioProfile(AudioProfile.Default, AudioScenario.Default);
 await encrypt(myChannel); //this is where i call encrypt function
 await AgoraRtcEngine.joinChannel(null, myChannel, null, 0);
}


Future<void> encrypt(String myChannel) async {
await AgoraRtcEngine.setEncryptionSecret(myChannel);
await AgoraRtcEngine.setEncryptionMode("aes-256-xts");

print('caller encrypted: ' + myChannel + ' in aes-256-xts');
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct for encrypting your channel ID.

But to encrypt this over a cross-platform you need to make sure that you add libagora-crypto.so and libcrypto.a file to your Android and iOS folder respectively.